# How to write a function to to draw a picture? I use some method. But it need to be improved

Tags: draw

Argument n s means an n-sides polygon with length equal to s, I try to use the help funciton to define the radians but the radian would change as the n chWhat I need to solve is how to keep the radian fixed when running the recursion. I need a solution to do that.

Answer (score 3):

You here make use of recursion. So the above will eventually error, since you make a call to `polygon (n-1) s`, and thus eventually `n` will be lower than `3`. A second problem is that `error` expects a string to raise an error, and an `error` is not very *idiomatic* Haskell.

If you omit the `error`, you will need some base case. That base case would likely need to return the empty list. That being said, you do not need recursion here in the first place. You can make use of `cycle` for example. In Haskell, usually a `Maybe a` or `Either String a` is returned for a non-total function. It will then return `Nothing`/`Left "errormessage"` in case the input is not correct, and a `Just x`, or `Right x` with the output.

Finally, you will need to use `fromIntegral` to convert the `Int` to a `Double`, and to calculate the amount of radians:

```
polygon :: Int -> Double -> Maybe [TurtleCommand]
polygon n s
    | n >= 3 && s >= 0 = Just (take (2*n) (cycle [Forward s, Turn rad]))
    | otherwise = Nothing
    where rad = 2*pi / fromIntegral n
```

For example:

```
Prelude> polygon 5 2
Just [Forward 2.0,Turn 1.2566370614359172,Forward 2.0,Turn 1.2566370614359172,Forward 2.0,Turn 1.2566370614359172,Forward 2.0,Turn 1.2566370614359172,Forward 2.0,Turn 1.2566370614359172]
Prelude> polygon 0 2
Nothing
Prelude> polygon 3 (-2)
Nothing
Prelude> polygon 3 1
Just [Forward 1.0,Turn 2.0943951023931953,Forward 1.0,Turn 2.0943951023931953,Forward 1.0,Turn 2.0943951023931953]
```

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is you are conflating two distinct concepts: the number of sides in the *final* figure (which does not decrease) and the number of sides *remaining* to draw (which *does* decrease). A pentagon, for example, is not drawn by drawing one side, then finishing with a square.

One way to think of this is figuring out what components you need, then how to combine them. For an `n`-polygon, you need `n` sides (represented by `Forward` values) and `n-1` vertices. (Correctly drawn, the last vertex is implied, because the last side will end where the first side began.)

```
import Data.List (intersperse, replicate)

-- Modifying Willem Van Onsem's design
-- (https://stackoverflow.com/a/57975195/1126841)
polygon :: Int -> Double -> Maybe [TurtleCommand]
polygon n _ | n < 3 = Nothing
polygon n s = let sides = replicate n (Forward s)
                  angle = 2 * pi / fromIntegeral n
                  vertex = Turn angle
              in Just (intersperse vertex sides)
```

Here, `intersperse :: a -> [a] -> [a]` takes an input list and builds a new list by inserting a given value between each element of the old one. For example:

```
> intersperse '-' "aaa"
"a-a-a"
```

For `polygon`, this means creating a list of the `Forward` values needed to draw the sides, then interspersing the `Turn` command to execute at each vertex.

---

Note too that, strictly speaking, you don't need any special handling for `n < 3`. `replicate` will return an empty list if its first argument is non-positive, and the two degenerate polygons with 1 and 2 sides can be represented as well:

- A 1-gon is just a single line segment with no turns
- A 2-gon is a line segment, a 180-degree turn, and a returning line segment.

`intersperse` effectively returns its original list in the case of an empty or singleton list. As such, you can simply write the following:

```
polygon :: Int -> Double -> [TurtleCommand]
polygon n s = let sides = replicate n (Forward s)
                  angle = 2 * pi / fromIntegeral n
                  vertex = Turn angle
              in intersperse vertex sides
```